# How do I make a td element the same width as the input element within?

Tags: html, css, width, html-table

I have a table consisting of a lot of input elements inside td elements.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <td class="first">
      <div>
        <input type="text" /> 
      </div>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The width of the input elements should be 20px. The width of the table is set to 100%. The input element in the first td should only have a min-width set so it will strech out (since the table has 100% width). I want the other inputs to have a fixed width (20px). When I do this the td elements has a much larger width than the input elements:

https://jsfiddle.net/cbzuwyrg/

Is it possible to make the td elements the same width as the input elements without setting the same width in css?

This fiddle shows what I want to achieve, but without having to set the width of the td to 20px: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cbzuwyrg/1/

Comment: do you want all the td to be the same width as the input ?

Comment: Yes, same width as the input within

Comment: so if the input for example has 80px width the td should be the same as it ?

Comment: Yes that is what I want

Comment: See the fiddle I just added to the question

Comment: yea checking it right now

Comment: @Laith It worked perfectly! I used css width insteadof size. I will accept the answer

Comment: damn deleted the comment by wrong https://jsfiddle.net/LaithSJ20/cbzuwyrg/4/ no worries bro just check this code too see if its working

Comment: i think it will work with you =) just posted the answer .

Comment: @Laith: you changed the code in the second jsfiddle - this code does not work at all

Comment: which one sir ?

Comment: You deleted the original jsfiddle you posted here in the comments (which is the one I am reffering to as "working perfectly", then you posted a second one which does not work.

Comment: let me reread the Q and work on it .

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work with you too .

Edit : i edited the code so all `td`s be the same size as the input .

```css
table {
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td.first{
  width:auto;
   border: 1px solid #000;
  }
 input[type="text"] {
     width: 100%; 
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <td class="first">
    <div>
      <input type="text" size="2"> 
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="first">
    <div>
      <input type="text" size="7"> 
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="first">
    <div>
      <input type="text" size=""> 
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="first">
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="last" size="" > 
    </div>
  </td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The code is html and CSS no JavaScript were used .

Comment: I think you changed the original code you showed me in the comment - If you see the fiddle showing the result I want this does not look anything like that. The td should be the width of the input. In your example the td is much larger than the input.

Comment: @slowpoke123 if i do remember you wanted the first td to be auto and no change to the others , and thats what i did .

Comment: @slowpoke123 in the code , if you changed the size of the input you will see the `td` changing with the size while the others are still the same . was not that what you asked for ?

Comment: if you read my question again, I want the td's to be the same width as the input. See the jsfiddle I posted in the question.

Comment: The table should have the width set to 100%

Comment: @slowpoke123 hope you like it now lol , is this good ? i updated the answer again .

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <td class="first">
    <div>
      <input type="text" /> 
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div style="width:8px">
      <input type="text" /> 
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div style="width:8px">
      <input type="text" /> 
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div style="width:8px">
      <input type="text" /> 
    </div>
  </td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Add the width size to your div's

Comment: The width is already set on the input elements (Legacy code).

Comment: Yes, but setting the with on your <div> will fix it. You can even takeout the div and set the with on your <td>

Comment: Yes, but at this point I can not change the legacy code and I wanted a solution resolved with only css and not javascript.

Comment: There is no javascript being used?

Comment: he wanted the first `td` to be auto and the others stays like what they are , well pretty much .

Comment: Yeah so there is about 800 files containg the structure where the width is set on the input elements. If css had some way of selecting the parent of a class selector this would be easly done - but yeah that is not possible. Therefore I would had to use javascript to set the width on the div or the td (because it is the input elements that is holding the information)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the scss you are writing can be more useful if you nest it properly, this works fine just adding a calc and nesting the scss code. I hope it can helps.

In this case the td's with 20px of width use a class that stablish that width, and the inputs have a calc because when you use 100% width they use the whole space until next input.

Sass:

```
table {
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  td {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   //display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;

    div {
      input {
        width: calc(100% - 4px) ;      
        &.td20 {
          width: 20px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <td class="first">
    <div>
      <input type="text" /> 
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="td20"/> 
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="td20" /> 
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="td20" /> 
    </div>
  </td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here you can see it working: https://jsfiddle.net/javierdp/adtj2t3o/8/

Comment: This is almost what I want - but without having to to set a width on the td elements. I want to achieve this with only setting width on the input elements.

Comment: Hi @slowpoke123 jsfiddle is updated, i hope it can help you!